# Should a native Android app free OpenGL resources when it is suspended?

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es

I have a bit newbie question about native Adroid apps. Should I free OpenGL resources when the app is suspended?

For example, in my application based on [QT OpenGLUnderQML sample](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-squircle-cpp.html) QQuickWindow::sceneGraphInvalidated is never called on Android, and the app does not free OpenGL resources when it is suspended and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of freeing resources is that your app is less likely to be ejected when the device is under memory pressure. Also you're being a better citizen, if everyone freed their resources in the background, then far more apps could stay alive at once in the background.

The disadvantage is it's a hassle to code, and you're going to have to do loading when users return to your app, which is going to take some time and will cause a slightly worse user experience.

There's no requirement to free resources, and I don't generally worry much about it in the games I've worked on. I occasionally deal with a few low-hanging fruit, like freeing up render-targets or flushing out low priority textures that are managed by a caching system. It probably never represents more than 10-20% of the OpenGL memory footprint, but I guess it means that a user with little memory is more likely to find my app still running if they multi-task for a moment to check their email or something.

Comment: good answer, the other question is why QQuickWindow::sceneGraphInvalidated is called on Desktop, but is not called on Android?